# How do I join all these meshes together? I already tried assigning all UV maps the same name

Tags: mesh, materials, uv, texture-painting

Every time I join them all, the materials get all jumbled up.

Before joining:

[image]

After joining:

[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pc_92zEuyhJ8JkPq7ySQMOHOTbbX1Yq-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pc_92zEuyhJ8JkPq7ySQMOHOTbbX1Yq-/view?usp=sharing

Here's the file for my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a Solidify modifier to create the outline which refers to the outline material by index. Every time you join an object, the material indices shift, and your setup breaks as a result. You need to carefully join one object at a time and update the index set on the Solidify modifier as needed. Please note that all objects will use the same modifiers list after they are joined. Joining everything may not work, since they don't currently use the same modifiers list.

[image: Solidify]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You're welcome!